# Can't change body background and body font at the same time

Tags: html, css

Hey guys so basically I've been learning html and Css these past couple of days. I'm having trouble assigning a background color and font color at the same time.

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

<meta charset = "UTF-8" >
<title>Practice blog</title>
</head>
<body style="color: blue;">
<body style="background-color:lightblue;">
```

So basically if I put the background color one on top the font of the text won't change, only the background. If I put the one where it changes the font the background won't  change. What can I do about that?

Comment: Can't have two body tags like that.

Comment: The second body element is overwriting the first body element which has the color styled on it. You should only have one element for body then you can add multiple inline or computed styles using CSS with a class or other selector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Congratulations on starting your journey with learning HTML and CSS!

Two things to keep in mind:

- Each HTML file can have only 1 body tag. A good way to think of it is that one HTML file corresponds to one page and each page has one body!
- Inline CSS isn't the prettiest way to learn and I think frowned upon. Making a separate CSS file and linking it to your HTML file will make learning a lot easier for you! Helped me a ton!

Comment: I have a question with the external stylesheet. I know how to style like the body and stuff with it. But lets say I wanted to style a <p> to be a certain color. How do I style that certain paragraph in the style sheet.

Comment: @Youssef1781 There are a lot of CSS tutorials in many languages. Here is the [Mozilla MDN tutorial about CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/CSS_basics). You can add a `class` to the p tag to style it differently, for example. Or you can use a specific selector (for example, `:first-child` for the first `p` tag.

Comment: @PeterKrebs I'm still a little confused. Could you show me an example of how to specify which p tag. I also made a question about it on my profile, so you could answer there if you want.

Comment: People were already answering you there. If you still don't understand, just read a tutorial about CSS or a watch a video. You can also just google "how to use css classes" or something.

Answer (score 0):

You need only one body:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Practice blog</title>
</head>

<body style="color: blue; background-color:lightblue;">
  Some text to show colors
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what others suggested, you could also use **internal CSS** to style the elements in the body without needing to use two body elements. What you need to do is embed the CSS code in the *style* tag of the *head*:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
background-color: blue;
color: yellow; /*or any colour of your own choice*/
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p> Paragraph whose colour will become yellow </p>
</body>
</html>
```

The code inside the style tags is called internal CSS which is an alternative way of styling the body elements. This is the easiest and simplest way of styling the body elements. Here's a demonstration:

```css
body {
background-color: blue;
color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<p> This is a simple paragraph </p>
```

The `background-color` will change the background colour of the body and the `color` will change the colour of the elements inside body i.e. paragraphs, headings etc.